# $(event.target).attr("data-bar") undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

jQuery is showing some very strange behavior regarding accessing a custom data attribute.

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="foo2" data-bar="bar" class="baz">some text</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#mainPage").on("click", "[id^='foo']", doSomething);

});
    

function doSomething(e) {
    var bar = $(e.target).attr("data-bar");
}
```

This gives `bar = undefined`

However

```
function doSomething(e) {
        e.target
        var bar = $(e.target).attr("data-bar");
    }
```

gives `bar = "bar"`

I'm finding it utterly bizarre. On the Chrome debugging console it clearly  shows the dataset or target holding `bar: "bar"`but without the `e.target` it returns `undefined`. Is this some kind of bug?

Comment: use $(this) instead of $(e.target)

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/suLufgyt/ and check the console

Comment: I have no output to the console.

Comment: are you clicking the text?

Comment: No repro ~ https://jsfiddle.net/t7ohmy2s/

Answer (score 0):

Using `$(this)` or `$(e.target)` work. Is your foo div inside an element with the id mainPage?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mainPage").on("click", "[id^='foo']", doSomething);
});


function doSomething(e) {
  console.log($(e.target).attr("data-bar"));
  console.log($(this).attr('data-bar'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body id='mainPage'>
  <div id="foo2" data-bar="bar" class="baz">some text</div>
</body>
```

Comment: No, $(e.target) does not work. As I said the console clearly shows e has the target of foo2 and that foo2 has a dataset with with "bar" stored in bar, but it is returning undefined unless I mysteriously place e.target above it. Yes it is inside a div with the id #mainPage.

Comment: run the code snippet above, click on some text and look at the console, both options work